# power bi create table with combined data from two other tables

Tags: mysql, datatable, powerbi, dax

I have two tables that contain different data. One has the following structure:

```
Postal code | City | Delivery Time | Delivery Date | ...
  14000     | Caen |   10:21:02    |   12.11.2023  | ...  
  14003     | Caen3|   10:31:15    |   12.11.2023  | ...
```

The second table has Postal codes with city names and postal code groupes like:

```
Postal code | City  |   PCgroup     | ...
  14003     | Caen3 |     14000     | ...
  14001     | Caen1 |     14000     | ...
```

"PCgroup" column in the second table groups several child postal codes under its parent postal code. So I want to **create a table that will apply this grouping** to the first table (also taking city name from the second table), in order to have something similar to the following:

```
Postal code | PCgroup| City | Delivery Time | Delivery Date | ...
  14000     | 14000  | Caen |   10:21:02    |   12.11.2023  | ...  
  14001     | 14000  | Caen |   10:28:00    |   12.11.2023  | ...  
  14003     | 14000  | Caen |   10:31:15    |   12.11.2023  | ...
```

I'am quite new to Power BI and I wasn't able to find this same problem resolved somewhere.
How can I resolve this issue and how should I proceed next time I have something similar to do ?

Comment: What you are looking for is "Merge queries" - see [Merge queries overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/merge-queries-overview)

Comment: Thank you, actually that helped and I could merge these two tables, thanks!